# Using express STATIC to server filesin NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

Im attempting to serve files with the assistance of express.static and am having difficulty getting it to work.

My code includes the following:

```
var app             = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var app_router = express.Router();

    app_router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('/test.html');
    });

app.use('/', app_router);
```

This does not function in serving test.html, however if I replace it with ./public/test.html it is served correctly(Basically bypassing express.static)

Any assistance would be appreciated. Ive looked around and found code similar to mine that appears to be working however I must be missing something relatively simple and would appreciate another set of eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding `express.static()`.

`res.sendFile()` takes a path to a file on disk, and has nothing to do with `express.static()`.

`express.static()` handles requests to paths matching files in the folder you pass it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes totall misunderstanding on my part there. Thank you!